# Giving admin rights to uninstall a program

Tags: c#, controls, panel, registrykey

I want to delete a registry key while uninstall the program. It can be done when run the visual studio as administrator and uninstalling using visual studio. But it doesn't happen, if I uninstall it using control panel. So is there any way to delete registry key while uninstalling the program.

Comment: Sure there's a way, but we'd need to know how you made your install program

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have an application manifest and just change the "requestedExecutionLevel" to Admin like below.

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This is based on if you've made the installer as a seperate application. Also, when uninstalling, it will request for confirmation with a UAC popup.